# Django: Select one row for each unique value of a field (column)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-postgresql

I have the following model in my Django application; I want to get a queryset of my model with **only one row** for every unique value of a field (I do not care which row that would be at this point).

The problem is I cannot use the `distinct` function, because I am using annotations in my query.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

### My model

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    # some other fields here
    start = models.DateTimeField()
```

### Notes

- This is basically the Django version of this StackOverflow question: [SQLAlchemy: Selecting one row for each distinct value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467928/sqlalchemy-selecting-one-row-for-each-distinct-value-of-a-column)

Comment: Can you please add the annotation query that you're using?

Comment: Sure thing!


    Slot.objects.annotate(
            pickup_count=Sum(Case(
                When(pickups__status='submitted', then=1),
                default=0,
                output_field=models.IntegerField(),
            )),
        ).filter(
            start__gt=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1),
        ).order_by('start')

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pain Django ORM. However this is possible with using SQL. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Comment: bro use SQL only...It more flex...

Comment: Well, I've used annotate like this before in a similar query. I think this should work:
Slot.objects.annotate( pickup_count=Sum(Case( When(pickups__status='submitted', then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField()))).filter( start__gt=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1), ).order_by('distinct_field', 'start').distinct('distinct_field')

Comment: You just need to pass the field that you want distinct as first field in order_by. Tell me if it works!